# How do I remove all loose edges?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I have cut a hole in a plane, but I am left with some loose edges.

Is there an easy way to select and delete them all?

See this screenshot:

[image]

See this edges siting out with no face?

Comment: What did you use to delete? Is it possible you used *Only Edges and Faces*? Does this still happen if you use *Faces*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Select the vertex and the end of one, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>*> Amount of adjacent faces*:

[image]

[image]

Then delete. (<kbd>Delete</kbd>*> Vertices*)

Answer (score 14):

Select the menu item *Mesh -> Cleanup -> Delete Loose, options for verts/edges/faces*.

Blender 2.70 and later.